# Wordpress site is getting blocked because of htaccess file

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

My Wordpress  site is getting blocked frequently.if i delete the following code from htaccess file it is working fine.This code is adding automatically.

```
# BEGIN iThemes Security - Do not modify or remove this line
# iThemes Security Config Details: 2
# Ban Hosts - Security > Settings > Banned Users
SetEnvIF REMOTE_ADDR "^157\.48\.9\.55$" DenyAccess
SetEnvIF X-FORWARDED-FOR "^157\.48\.9\.55$" DenyAccess
SetEnvIF X-CLUSTER-CLIENT-IP "^157\.48\.9\.55$" DenyAccess

SetEnvIF REMOTE_ADDR "^157\.48\.9\.96$" DenyAccess
SetEnvIF X-FORWARDED-FOR "^157\.48\.9\.96$" DenyAccess
SetEnvIF X-CLUSTER-CLIENT-IP "^157\.48\.9\.96$" DenyAccess

SetEnvIF REMOTE_ADDR "^157\.48\.13\.158$" DenyAccess
SetEnvIF X-FORWARDED-FOR "^157\.48\.13\.158$" DenyAccess
SetEnvIF X-CLUSTER-CLIENT-IP "^157\.48\.13\.158$" DenyAccess

SetEnvIF REMOTE_ADDR "^157\.48\.21\.54$" DenyAccess
SetEnvIF X-FORWARDED-FOR "^157\.48\.21\.54$" DenyAccess
SetEnvIF X-CLUSTER-CLIENT-IP "^157\.48\.21\.54$" DenyAccess

SetEnvIF REMOTE_ADDR "^157\.48\.23\.210$" DenyAccess
SetEnvIF X-FORWARDED-FOR "^157\.48\.23\.210$" DenyAccess
SetEnvIF X-CLUSTER-CLIENT-IP "^157\.48\.23\.210$" DenyAccess

SetEnvIF REMOTE_ADDR "^113\.31\.81\.34$" DenyAccess
SetEnvIF X-FORWARDED-FOR "^113\.31\.81\.34$" DenyAccess
SetEnvIF X-CLUSTER-CLIENT-IP "^113\.31\.81\.34$" DenyAccess

SetEnvIF REMOTE_ADDR "^176\.104\.99\.97$" DenyAccess
SetEnvIF X-FORWARDED-FOR "^176\.104\.99\.97$" DenyAccess
SetEnvIF X-CLUSTER-CLIENT-IP "^176\.104\.99\.97$" DenyAccess

SetEnvIF REMOTE_ADDR "^43\.239\.245\.245$" DenyAccess
SetEnvIF X-FORWARDED-FOR "^43\.239\.245\.245$" DenyAccess
SetEnvIF X-CLUSTER-CLIENT-IP "^43\.239\.245\.245$" DenyAccess

SetEnvIF REMOTE_ADDR "^2405:0?204:66a9:f91e:f8dc:a001:2b38:d67b$" DenyAccess
SetEnvIF X-FORWARDED-FOR "^2405:0?204:66a9:f91e:f8dc:a001:2b38:d67b$" DenyAccess
SetEnvIF X-CLUSTER-CLIENT-IP "^2405:0?204:66a9:f91e:f8dc:a001:2b38:d67b$" DenyAccess
```

Comment: And you don't think that it makes sense to check your iThemes settings?

Comment: @arkascha didnt use any theme developed the theme i didnt find any theme settings

Comment: You _did_ read the comments you yourself posted which are automatically added to your configuration file? Or did you not read it and instead think "I do not care, I will just ask others to do my work for me..."? Sorry for the sarcasm, but that is _your_ system, _you_ have access and can control it. The system _tells you_ where those lines come from. Still you ask us...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deactivate the Plugin *iThemes Security* or simply delete its folder in wp-content/plugins

Answer (score 1):

These lines in htaccess are added by iThemes Security plugin. You must disable and remove the plugin and remove lines from htaccess to stop blocking IP addresses.